# How can I extract the hour part from a duration value in Excel?

Tags: excel

How can I convert duration in excel to text ? I am having 1037:00:00 in a cell, which is the sum of certain durations. I want to extract 1037 alone. Excel returns "hours" when I try to extract with MID or use TEXT function.

Comment: What you ask has nothing with conversion to text. If you want to extract a *time* component you should use time related functions, not string manipulation

Comment: Even you can use split(":")

Comment: Excel doesn't have a duration format and `1037:00:00` isn't a time value. This means that this is just text. `LEFT(A1,4)` would return the first component directly. `LEFT(B1;FIND(":";B1)-1)` would actually look for the first colon

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos put 23:00:00 in a cell, and copy it down.  Then place sum(range of 23 hours) at the bottom.  I wound up with 598:00:00,  When I switch the format from custom to general I wind up with 24.91667.  So yes you can have more than 24 hours displayed

Comment: @ForwardEd that's just text. The only thing that changes is the *cell format*. A time format will display "12:00: AM". What you see is a number displayed with a *custom* format. In Excel, everything is text or a number and the different "types" are just display styles

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Exactly so I have time greater than 24 hours being displayed.  its still a number that is manipulated.  If it was text in the cell when I change it to general format what is being displayed in the cell would not change.  You original comment says its not a time value, but it is a time value.  the 598:00:00 being display is a time value in excel using a custom format.  Hence why I am disagreeing with you when you say its text.  I can even do `=istext()` and get a false return.

Comment: @ForwardEd you missed the point "598:00:00" is just the formatted text. The underlying value is a *number*. Excel doesn't have dates, times or durations. Dates and times are just decimals where the integer part is the date part and the fractional is the time. When you typed "23:00" Excel stored `0.95833333`. The sum was just another number that was displayed using the `[h]:mm:ss` format. In fact, you can divide that sum by 24 and get the value that is displayed as hours

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But your original comment states that this is text.  Its not.  Its a number.  In fact when I do a left(Cell,3) its does not return 598.  I agree its a number.  I disagree that its ok to call it text.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos : Excel does have a duration format under Time > Type (37:30:55). I have formatted the cells like this. I am summing the outage duration of GSM cells. So it is stored as time and I need only the hour part for further calculations.

Answer (score 2):

If it is really the sum of some durations you can get the amount of hours by multiplying the cell by 24. The internal representation of a date or time cell is the number of days since beginning of the year 1900, so you have to multiply it by 24 to get the number of hours. (The year 1900 is not interesting for you as you just want a time span.) The `Hour` function does not work here because you get the day hour which is 5 in this case.

Be sure to format your target cell as regular number.

Comment: Thank You Fratyx. Multiplying with 24 after extracting the required length in a cell formatted as regular number did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

lets assume your cell with **1037:00:00** is in cell **L40**.  You can use the following formula to pull the hours.

```
=INT(L40)*24+HOURS(L40)
```

Note this will only pull full hours rounded down.  It does not take into account minutes or seconds.

Alternatives:

```
=Rounddown(L40*24,0)
```

This alternative is what Fratyx explained in his answer.