# Time duration value in Excel under 1h shifted from minutes to hours

Tags: excel, time, duration

I need to import an excel file with time duration values in it. One source has a problem with their sheets where the time values have shifted so that the minute's value now shows as hours and the seconds as minutes. Here is an example:

**Value should be 00:31:26 but shows as 31:26:00.**
The actual value of the cell is 1900/01/01  07:26:00 ??

***excel screenshot:***

[image]

I have tried different cell formats, adding, subtracting but no joy. Short of pasting these values out to notepad and manually fixing them I have not found a solution.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

PS> I have contacted the source to fix it, but no word as yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the source values are **consistently wrong** and the source doesn't fix them... you can create a new time with total hours as minutes and minutes as seconds. Cell formula to display the shifted value from `A1`:

```
=TIME(0;A1*24;MINUTE(A1))
```

See also: [How can I extract the hour part from a duration value in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761106/how-can-i-extract-the-hour-part-from-a-duration-value-in-excel)

### edit

You can shorten it to just divide by 60. I still leave the more verbosive approach in the answer, because you may want to apply different transformations on the values.

```
=A1/60
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much @grek40! Geez, at the end I could have just divided by 60. This will help me a hell of a lot.